# How to display single value from the database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a table in my html page having name, value1 and value2 in one sql table and value3 and value4 in another sql table.  Now I want to find the minimum of (value3-value2) and display it in another small html table and in the same table I want to display the corresponding name whose value is minimum(value3-value2) using codeigniter.  Plz help me for this how i can write Model, Controller and view.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have the methods for fetching the values1-4. Now you just have to pass that data trough you view from the table3 method and there you just use the build in php function `min($array)`. Refference: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.min.php